# System.Net.Security no longer has BeginRead

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, moonapns

I'm trying to use [`moon-apns`](https://github.com/arashnorouzi/Moon-APNS) in my .NET core 1 project. However, when I moved the required files over to my project, it looks like `sslStream` no long has `BeginRead()`. The version of sslStream in the moon-apns project has this at the top of the sslStream.cs file:

```
#region Assembly System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Where as the sslStream.cs file in my project has:

```
#region Assembly System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

Comment: `BeginRead` is inherited from `System.IO.Stream`. It isn't displayed as an actual member.

Comment: Are you targeting .NET Core / DNX / Xamarin or some other target? You can't use the .NET Framework's DLLs, this may be the reason your `SslStream` class (from the wrong assembly) can't find `System.IO.Stream` and its inherited members (like `BeginRead`).

Comment: Oh that might be why. I think this project i'm trying to reference is targeted towards .net40 or .net45 whereas mine is .net core 1. Is that going to be an issue?

Comment: Is there an alternative to BeginRead in .NET Core?

Comment: .NET Core 1.x does not have `Stream.BeginRead` but it was added in .NET Core 2.0 ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.beginread ). I'm curious why you're targeting .NET Core 1 because it's largely obsolete. However you should consider using `ReadAsync` instead.

Comment: I was tasked with taking over this project. The original developer used .NET Core 1.0 for some reason. I tried migrating to .NET Core2.0, but wasn't able to do it successfully.